# Buying AntMiner L3+

Tags: antminer

I am looking to get started with a AntMiner L3+. Bitmain.com says "Coming Soon" for the last few days. However, I see these being sold in eBay & Alibaba for prices ranging from $800 to $4500.

Why would the manufacturer say "coming soon" but being sold by others. How is that the price is so far apart. I am confused and don't know where to start.

I would like to know the correct price for this unit and a legitimate place to buy one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmain.com releases their machines in batches. When it is sold out they update the site as "Coming Soon" as if they are yet to launch the product.

Also they ship it few months after the purchase. The batch I bought was sold at $2040 USD paid in bitcoin cash.